# How are time namespaces supposed to be used?

Tags: linux, namespace, clock, unshare

I thought I could do something like:

```
sudo unshare -T bash -c 'date -s "$1" && foobar' sh "$(date -d -1day)"
```

so `foobar` would see a different system time from the rest of the system. However, it seems the change of system time is not contained. It changes the system time of the whole system.

[This LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/766089/) seems to suggest this namespace was meant for the use I tried to give it.

> System calls that adjust the system time will, when called outside of the root time namespace, adjust the namespace-specific offsets instead.

Looking at `strace date -s ...`, I see among other output:

```
clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {tv_sec=1619044910, tv_nsec=0}) = 0
```

However, reading `time_namespaces(7)`:

> This affects various APIs that measure against these clocks, including: clock_gettime(2), clock_nanosleep(2), nanosleep(2), timer_settime(2), timerfd_settime(2), and /proc/uptime.

I see it doesn't mention `clock_settime(2)`. The wording "including" tells me this is perhaps not the complete list, but maybe it is.

I also don't understand `--boottime`/`--monotonic`. Looking at `clock_settime(2)`, I see:

> CLOCK_MONOTONIC A  nonsettable  system-wide clock that represents monotonic time since—as described by POSIX—"some unspecified point in the past".  On Linux, that point corresponds to the number of seconds that the system has been running since it was booted.

> CLOCK_BOOTTIME (since Linux 2.6.39; Linux-specific) A  nonsettable  system-wide  clock  that is identical to CLOCK_MONOTONIC, except that it also includes any time that the system is suspended.

However, when trying them, they don't seem to change the `uptime`:

```
$ uptime -s
2021-04-10 10:30:45
$ sudo unshare -T --boottime 1000000000 uptime -s
2021-04-10 10:30:45
$ sudo unshare -T --monotonic 1000000000 uptime -s
2021-04-10 10:30:45
$ sudo unshare -T --boottime -100000 uptime -s
2021-04-10 10:30:45
$ sudo unshare -T --monotonic -100000 uptime -s
2021-04-10 10:30:45
```

I see from `strace uptime` that it reads `/proc/uptime` instead of calling `clock_gettime(2)`, and `/proc/uptime` doesn't seem to be affected by the `unshare` calls and their offsets, despite the documentation at `time_namespaces(7)` saying that it affects `/proc/uptime` as I quoted above.

How is this namespace supposed to be used? I can't seem to find any command that would be affected by `unshare --time`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see three main points in your reasoning that need clarification:

---

**The first one** is that unsharing a time-namespace affects the *children* spawned *from then on* by the process that called the `unshare(2)`. The calling process itself is unaffected. This is a bit like PID namespaces and unlike the other namespace types so far. However, the calling process *may* still enter that newly created time-namespace, it's just that if it wants to do so then it also has to `setns(2)` (i.e. `nsenter(1)` in CLI parlance) itself into it.

All this means that the `unshare -T` commands you've been running never really moved those commands into the newly made time-namespace. You can just add the `-f` option to `unshare(1)` to make it run the specified command as its child instead of `execve(2)` itself into it. That way the specified command will live into that time-namespace.

Naturally, as you've been doing correctly, you also want to specify the `--boottime` and/or `--monotonic` options to "warp" that time-namespace's vision of those clocks, otherwise the child time-namespace would simply have the same vision as its parent.

So, to cap it all, taking your attempt as an example, on my machine:

```bsh
$ sudo unshare -T --boottime 1000000000 uptime -s
2021-04-23 11:07:10
$ sudo unshare -fT --boottime 1000000000 uptime -s
1989-08-15 09:20:30
$
```

Alternatively to using those convenient options, you may set the `/proc/self/timens_offsets` file manually as long as you do it prior to spawning any child. The "manual" equivalent of the above would be something like:

```bsh
$ sudo unshare -T dash -c 'echo "boottime 1000000000 0" > /proc/self/timens_offsets; uptime -s'
1989-08-15 09:20:30
```

Here I'm using `dash` just to use a leaner shell that certainly does not spawn children for its own bootstrap and that also has a *builtin* echo (so as not to spawn a child for it) to go setting its own `timens_offsets` file. From then on, all subsequent commands run by `dash` will see a "warped" boottime.

*But not* if you rather do `exec uptime -s`, because that would replace `dash` with `uptime` hence still living in the parent time-namespace, *unless* you also `nsenter(1)` beforehand. Consider:

```bsh
$ sudo unshare -T dash -c 'echo "boottime 1000000000 0" > /proc/self/timens_offsets; exec uptime -s'
2021-04-23 11:07:10
$ sudo unshare -T dash -c 'echo "boottime 1000000000 0" > /proc/self/timens_offsets; exec nsenter --time=/proc/self/ns/time_for_children uptime -s'
1989-08-15 09:20:30
$
```

---

**The second point** I see that needs clarification is regarding the `date` command specifically.

Note that [as of kernel v5.11](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/namespace.c?h=linux-5.11.y#n329) (as well as current latest v5.12-rc8) only `CLOCK_BOOTIME` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` can be "warped" in a new time-namespace, as it is also stated in the [NOTES of `time_namespaces(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time_namespaces.7.html#NOTES):

> Note that time namespaces do not virtualize the CLOCK_REALTIME
> clock.  Virtualization of this clock was avoided for reasons of
> complexity and overhead within the kernel.

However, `date` specifically acts on the `CLOCK_REALTIME` clock as you can notice from your `strace date -s ...` command. This means that, at the time I'm writing this, the `date` command is still quite unaffected by the time-namespace it lives in.

A quick example of command that *is* indeed affected by the time-namespace because it refers to `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is `dmesg`. Try something like:

```bsh
$ sudo unshare -fT --monotonic 1000000000 dmesg -T
```

---

**The third** point seems to be about this quote:

> System calls that adjust the system time will, when called outside of the root time namespace, adjust the namespace-specific offsets instead.

Admittedly that is a bit misleading because (currently) it is clearly *not* possible to *arbitrarily* change a time-namespace's vision of time *afterwards*, simply because both `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` are in fact unchangeable. Those two clocks are *meant* to be unchangeable.

The only operation allowed is thus to "bootstrap" them to some offset (related to the initial time namespace) *before* any process has joined that time-namespace, so that no process will ever experience jumps (not even forwards) of those two clocks.

This is why the `unshare(2)` does not move the calling process into the newly created time-namespace: that way it (or some other process) has the opportunity to specify the "bootstrapping" offsets, which in fact cannot be changed after any one process entered the time-namespace. Computing the correct offset is obviously a delicate operation, and that is a job for a "namespace manager".

Comment: "The calling process itself is unaffected." -- For a moment, I thought you meant for all namespaces in general, but I see the time namespace is relatively special in this regard. Having the time namespace work like this makes sense when I re-read this sentence from a comment in the LWN article I linked: "If you're not careful, a migrated process has a high probability of seeing CLOCK_MONOTONIC going backward, for example, which is going to create confusion." I guess this is to avoid that.

Comment: @JoL Sort of, although that quote seems to be more related to the very existence of time-namespaces: migrating processes to other machines would definitely make them see different values of monotonic clocks, which is unwanted. See edited answer.

Comment: To be thorough, on architectures where `vdso(7)` is available to provide the time (like amd64) , the `clock_gettime(2)` syscall doesn't happen, but the vDSO `clock_gettime()` library call can still be seen with `ltrace` instead of `strace`, and one can indeed see its first arg is 0 <=> CLOCK_REALTIME.

Comment: "Note that time namespaces do not virtualize the CLOCK_REALTIME clock." - disappointing. Other than migrating VMs to different hosts, what use are time namespaces as currently implemented?

Comment: @Wodin Note that Linux Namespaces are used to implement _containers_, not full VMs. In fact, VMs even have their own `CLOCK_REALTIME` as emulated by the virtualizer (Qemu/KVM, Xen Hypervisor, etc.). I'm just conjecturing here but one use of time-namespaces may be for migrating, or simply stopping and restarting, containers. For instance, (re-)starting a container by priming its new time-namespace with the correct offset in relation to the container's previous time-namespace. Don't know whether orchestration engines such as Kubernetes actually allow that though.

Comment: Sure, but if you want a container that shares everything with the host, except that things like `date` return a time that is offset from the host, it seems you're out of luck. The migration (or pausing/unpausing) of containers is the apparent use case, yes. I was wondering if there were other use cases. (I should have said "containers" instead of "VMs".)